# Irish citizenship or Permanent residence after 5 years of residence for EU citizen and their non-EU Family?

Tags: european-union, ireland, naturalization

European Union law secures EU Citizens' right to travel in the member countries freely. They can also bring their non-EU family member(s) with them in certain instances.

[This](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/rights_of_residence_in_ireland/residence_rights_eu_national.html) page mentions that:

**Permanent residence**
These Regulations also introduced a right of permanent residence for EEA nationals and their family members after a five-year period of uninterrupted legal residence in the State.

[While](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/citizenship/become-an-irish-citizen-by-naturalisation/) this page mentions that:

**Adult application based on residence for UK, EU/EEA & Swiss nationals**

To apply for citizenship by naturalisation based on residence, you must prove that you have been resident in the State for at least 5 years (1825 or 1826 days) out of the last 9 years.

This includes 1 year (365 or 366 days) of continuous residence immediately before the date you apply.

---

Now does it mean that after 5 years of residence in Ireland, I (EU national) and my non-EU family members should apply for **PERMANENT RESIDENCE OR IRISH CITIZENSHIP?**

I am confused.

**EDIT:** Several informal sources also mention that Irish PR can be obtained after 5 years of residence (be it through employment, investment etc..). But one of the naturalization requirements is 5 years of residence. Why would one apply for PR when they can apply for Irish citizenship after 5 years of residence? Does Ireland have a concept of a PR like the UK's ILR or the American Green Card anyway? So many sources have puzzled me completely:(

DO NOTE THAT IRISH PR IS **NOT** A REQUIREMENT FOR NATURALIZATION. THERE IS JUST THIS CONTINUOUS 5 YEAR RESIDENCE REQUIREMENT, BESIDES OTHER THINGS.

Comment: @phoog Any idea about this one?

Comment: Ah, the pinging doesn't work except in response, so I did not see this before now.  Mark Johnson's answer is basically correct, though there are conditions that may be imposed, for example with regard to the uninterrupted nature of the period of residence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now does it mean that after 5 years of residence in Ireland, I (EU national) and my non-EU family members should apply for PERMANENT RESIDENCE OR IRISH CITIZENSHIP?

It seems to mean that you may each choose one option or the other.

> Why would one apply for PR when they can apply for Irish citizenship after 5 years of residence?

One possibility: the current citizenship would be lost by naturalizing, and the person does not wish to lose it.  There could be other reasons for preferring one or the other, of course.

Answer (score 2):

As an EU Citizen (and your EU family members), you are **automatically** a permanent resident after 5 years.

You *can* apply for a **permanent resident card** to document this.

Such a card would document the fact that you fulfill the 5 years required for naturalization, should you wish to also become an Irish citizen.

---

**Sources**:

- [Permanent residence (after 5 years) for EU nationals - Your Europe](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/eu-nationals-permanent-residence/index_en.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mark. Note that my family members are not EU nationals. But I believe they still can apply for a PR Card after 5 years of residence with me (EU national). So, **are you saying that I (an EU National) and my family members (who are NOT EU nationals) will be eligible for Irish citizenship after 5 years of residence in the Republic of Ireland, but to PROVE our residence, we ought to get a PR Card.** Is that right?

Comment: I guess there are so many reasonable ways to prove that we did reside in Ireland for 5 years such as immigration and travel history etc..Are you sure that a PR card is mandatory for Irish naturalization? Once I confirm answers to these questions, I will mark this answer as "accepted". Thanks

Comment: @JayShah I wrote **can** not *must*. It will assist you in the proof you need, but you are not required to apply for the card. For naturalization you must bring proof one way or another.

Comment: Okay. Irish naturalization is possible without getting a PR card, am I right? Those who don't wish to naturalize, there's then the option to get a PR card instead. Is this right? [I understand that a PR card is useful for naturalization purposes]

Comment: @JayShah Yes. In countries that have national ID cards, such a card is useful, but in Ireland probably less so.

Comment: @JayShah Your non eu family members would then get an Article 20 card instead of the present Article 10 card.

Comment: @JayShah to be precise, only certain family relationships qualify under the free movement directive.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for adding. I guess brothers, sisters, aunts, uncles are included under EU law provided they are members of household or need personal care(health or financial)?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that accepting @phoog's answer will "unaccept"  Mark's answer. I think both answers are good. My intuition tells me that I got more satisfied by phoog's direct answering of my asked questions so please allow me to discriminate and mark phoog's answer as accepted for the sake of SE rules.

Comment: @phoog Could you please also answer:https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/55004/what-is-meant-by-dependent-parent-under-eu-law

Comment: @MarkJohnson https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/55004/what-is-meant-by-dependent-parent-under-eu-law

Comment: @JayShah You should assume the dictionary definition of [DEPENDENT | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dependent): **needing the support of something or someone in order to continue existing or operating**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Do you think merely financial dependency means dependent in a dictionary sense?

Comment: @JayShah Financial dependence is one aspect, but **living with you** another. See **Sample story** in  [Registering your non-EU family members in another EU country - Your Europe](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/non-eu-family-members-residence-card/index_en.htm#:~:text=Your%20family%20members%20may%20use,have%20to%20move%20with%20them.)

Comment: @JayShah [EU Treaty Rights](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/EU%20Treaty%20Rights) does not apply to Family members of **Irish nationals** in Ireland.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I do know that. Thank you for reminding:)

Comment: @JayShah brothers, sisters, aunts and uncles may qualify on the basis of household membership or dependence (as can anyone, even if not legally related), but that means that you have to satisfy Ireland's criteria for determining whether they are in fact members of the household or are dependent.  Therefore it is not automatic.